# Subversion conflict with a deleted file

Tags: svn, conflict, delete-file

I have a file that I have removed from subversion, however in the mean time someone else has updated this file and it now is in conflict.

I have spoken to them and we are agreed that it should be deleted. Any ideas how we can stop it being in conflict?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the "check for modifications" command to get a list of changed files. There you can revert the conflicted file. This works in the commit dialog too.

Comment: `svn status | grep ^M`

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `svn resolved` command to remove the conflict state and commit again.

Comment: we are using toroiseSVN which doesnt have a command line interface. We have tried marking it as resolved, but as the files dont exist anymore then it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I use Linux so I don't have access to TortoiseSVN. You could try creating an empty file with that filename and mark it as resolved using the GUI, then delete it again (not svn delete) and commit. Marking as resolved is the way to do it, and I just tested it on a test repo I created.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and used **revert** on the folder that contained the deleted file given that the latest commit did not contain the file. The only problem is that you need to commit first any other changes you made in the folder